# A few questions about SQL Table partitioning and performance

Tags: sql, syntax, partitioning, oracle19c

Let's assume I have a TABLE like this one with milions of rows:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
( 
    id INT NOT NULL,
    fname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    lname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    partitiontag INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (partitiontag)  
(
        PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1),
        PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2),
        PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (3),
        PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

**1. Is there any performance difference between the following two queries?**

*a) SELECT * FROM test PARTITION(P1)*

*b) SELECT * FROM test WHERE partitiontag = 1*

**2. Is there any performance difference between the following three queries (WHERE id=5 as example, it can be fname = 'xxx' or sth)?**

*a) SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = 5*

*b) SELECT * FROM test PARTITION(P1) WHERE id = 5*

*c) SELECT * FROM test WHERE id=5 and partitiontag = 1*

**3. Is there any performance difference between the following three queries when we want to update/delete rows? - for example:**

*a) UPDATE TEST SET fname = 'Changed' WHERE id = 10;*

*b) UPDATE TEST SET fname = 'Changed' WHERE id = 10 and partitionTag = 1;*

*c) UPDATE TEST PARTITION(P1) SET fname = 'Changed' WHERE id = 10;*

Answer (score 1):

1. Optimizer is smart enough to find out that `partitiontag = 1` narrows the search to just one partition, therefore (a) and (b) are equivalent.
2. Since `id` is a primary key, all of these queries will use primary index. Just with (b) and (c) row would be filtered out if it is found outside of the partition. If instead of `id` you would filter on `fname`, then (a) would scan entire table (since there is no hint about partition), while (b) and (c) are equivalent and would both scan only a single partition.
3. Same as (2), update behaves in same way as select here.

It's definitely helpful to learn how to look at [explain plan](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/generating-and-displaying-execution-plans.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer mate ;) "Same as (2), update behaves in same way as select here." -> Does it really not help if I give a partition to the where clause in addition to the primary key? Doesn't it help the database to look for only one partition? Does it ever make sense to add something else to a where clause (in update/delete statements ofc) in order to speed up the query if we already have a clustered index (primary key) in the clause?